# How do I declare thousands of variables in Pyomo

Tags: python, variables, declaration, pyomo

How do I declare hundreds / thousands of variables in pyomo without writing out a line for each variable?

They all have the same bounds and domain.

Ie. is there a faster way of doing this:

```
import pyomo.kernel as pmo

x1 = pmo.variable(domain_type=pmo.RealSet, lb=-3, ub=3)
x2 = pmo.variable(domain_type=pmo.RealSet, lb=-3, ub=3)
...
x1000 = pmo.variable(domain_type=pmo.RealSet, lb=-3, ub=3)
```

Comment: Use a list: `x = [pmo.variable(domain_type=pmo.RealSet, lb=-3, ub=3) for _ in range(1000)]`

Comment: What you want is an indexed variable. Declare an indexing set first and then declare the variable.  There are examples in the documentation and on this site.